# Python export string columns to excel

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I have one column in my Data Frame with codes like this: 2106080119283699, 2104985492880938 for that I converted that column to string:

```
File['mtcn']=File['mtcn'].values.astype(str)
```

To avoid this when I export this Data Frame to excel: 5.47506e+09
But when I open the excel file the column looks good but If I click into the column the value change to:

[image]

I know that I can change the data type into excel to text and this would never happen but I want to know if there is a way to convert into the same python the value and after export to excel even if I click int the excel the column the code would keep this structure as: 2106080119283699

Regards

Comment: How are you exporting this to Excel? Your options include changing the cell format to Text from Python, or adding a `'` to the beginning of the number before exporting (I'm assuming the second option should work).

Comment: The cell/column format has to be changed first before into and edit the cell, otherwise Excel will "correct" the format to whatever it thinks is appropriate..

Comment: i suspect you just need to change the number format of those cells to show full range number.

Comment: Hi, this is how I export: full_path_hist=f'{Emailspath}{compiled}'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(full_path_hist, engine='xlsxwriter', )
ics_dub.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Duplicates', index=False)
ics_hist.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='ICS Only', index=False)